# Azure Data Warehouse: how to get local datetime into a variable?

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, utc

No matter where an Azure Data Warehouse database is located it always uses UTC (coordinated Universal Time) which is 4 hours ahead of our local (Toronto) time - 5 hours ahead in winter. We need a way to get the local time for time stamping our data and other operations.

UDF's wont work because they cant do selects. I've created a Stored Procedure that works but can't figure out how to assign the result to a local variable. That's what I'd like help with.

The stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[getLocalDate] AS
```

BEGIN
    declare @offset nvarchar(6), @intoffset integer,@return_value datetime

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
select @offset  = current_utc_offset from sys.time_zone_info where name='Eastern Standard Time';
select @intOffset = -convert(int,substring(@offset,3,1));
set @return_value= dateadd(hh,@intOffset,getDate()) 

select @return_value as localtime
```

END

exec dbo.getLocalDate

which correctly returns the local datetime:

localtime
2018-07-16 13:49:29.607

The problem is how to put that result into a local variable?

declare @localtime datetime

exec @localtime=dbo.getLocalDate

returns:
Parse error at line: 2, column: 6: Incorrect syntax near '@localtime'.

declare @localtime datetime

set @localtime=exec dbo.getLocalDate

returns:
Parse error at line: 2, column: 16: Incorrect syntax near 'exec'.

Can't use an OUTPUT parameter - Azure DW doesn't allow it.

Suggestions appreciated.

Bob K

Answer (score 0):

This ain't pretty but it works:

Declare @localDateTime datetime = (select  dateadd(hh,-convert(int,substring(current_utc_offset,3,1)),getDate()) from sys.time_zone_info where name='Eastern Standard Time');

Now @localDateTime can be used in our queries.

Bob K